# Rails - net/http is working but same request is not working in httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do a request in httparty but it's not working

```
require 'httparty'

module PvWatch
  class Client
    include HTTParty

    # base_uri ENV["pv_watch_endpoint"]

    def login
      response = self.class.post('http://pvwatch.xxx.xxx.xxx.net/api/v1/login', options)
    end

    def options
      {
        headers: {
          'content-type' => 'application/json',
          'access-key' => 'FORGET ABOUT THIS',
          'authorization' => 'uri=api/v1/login'
        },
        body: {
          username: "case",
          password: "123"
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

the weird thing is that when i do the request with net/http is working and i don't know what i'm doing wrong with httparty

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

module PvWatch
  class Client
    def login
      url = URI("http://pvwatch.xxx.xxx.xxx.net/api/v1/login")

      http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
      request["content-type"] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      request["access-key"] = 'FORGET ABOUT THIS'
      request["authorization"] = 'uri=api/v1/login'
      request.body = "username=case&password=123"

      response = http.request(request)
      puts response.read_body
    end
  end
end
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Define `not working` - what did you expect and what was the actual outcome?

Comment: I don't know what `postman-token` is for, but I don't see it in your request using httparty.

Comment: the httparty returns {success false} "provide your username" and net/http is returning success true.... I'm sorry about the postman token, i got the code from postan to check if it was working and it did

Comment: It seems like httparty is changing the body request before sending to the api

Comment: Looks like you're sending the wrong Content-Type in the HTTParty version. Try changing that to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: It worked after adding application/x-www-form-urlencoded... yeeeeei!